# Corba Coonection port stuck at 900 and causing COMM FAILURE

Tags: java, corba, orb

Running my Corba program causes the error below.

`com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 10.80.2.159; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
...
...
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1177)`

Using `tnameserv -ORBInitialPort [Any port number]` has not worked
Using  `orbd -ORBInitialPort 2000 -port 1999` or `orbd -ORBInitialPort 2000` has not worked.
I cannot find any orb.properties file, or I do not know where to look.
I am on a public shared network for Comp Sci students at my university.
The error always says port 900

Comment: more detail about your ORB in particular.  Perhaps some source code.  nmap -p 900 10.80.2.159 might provide useful data.  And then, nmap from the other machine of course. (I claim no expertise, just my two cents.) Maybe `nc` would be more useful than `nmap`.